# sum column to show total in every row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select Group, Sum(columnA) as SumColumn
FROM table
GROUP BY Group
```

I get results looking like this

```
+-----+---------+
|Group|SumColumn|
+-----+---------+
|A    |10       |
+-----+---------+
|B    |20       |
+-----+---------+
```

How can I change/add to this to show something like this?

```
+-----+---------+-----------+
|Group|SumColumn|TotalColumn|
+-----+---------+-----------+
|A    |10       |30         |
+-----+---------+-----------+
|B    |20       |30         |
+-----+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is hard to see what your data looks like -- but from what you posted this is what you want:

```
SELECT Name, 
       SumColumn,
       SUM(SumColumn) AS TotalColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT Group as Name, SUM(columnA) AS SumColumn
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY Group
) T
```

You might want this -- depending on other stuff.

```
SELECT *,  
       SUM(columnA) OVER (PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY Group) AS SumColumn,
       SUM(columnA) OVER (PARTITION BY Group) AS TotalColumn
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Partition was the Key word i could not remember! thanks!

Comment: @wondergoat77 - remember use the ORDER BY to do the "incremental" sum results as in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this answer correct? I mean I'm looking at the second solution you provided, the one that avoids the subquery. Your 'subtotal' and 'grandtotal' columns are the same ... also it would return the entire result set (every row) with (sum by group) listed twice in columns 2 and 3. You need something like sum(columnnA) over (partition by All) to have the grand total in every row. And would still need a group by statement.

Comment: @user45867 -- no.  The way windowing functions work is they assume a specific range if it is not specified so these two are `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.  What you are describing is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` which would need to be specified in the windowing clause after the `ORDER BY`.  Also, you don't need a group by statement with windowing functions -- that is the point of windowing functions -- they are a "group by" on a single row.

Answer (score 6):

Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT [Group], Sum(columnA) as SumColumn, 
       TotalColumn = (SELECT SUM(columnA) FROM dbo.Table1)
FROM dbo.Table1
GROUP BY [Group]
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75177/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: @Hogan: no, that's not how the sql-server optimizer works. That's a simple subquery and not a correlated subquery. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-starters-simple-and-correlated-subqueries

Answer (score 6):

You can actually mix window functions and aggregation functions in a `select` statement.  So, you can do this without subqueries:

```
select Group, Sum(columnA) as SumColumn,
       sum(sum(columnA)) over () as TotalColumns
FROM table
GROUP BY Group;
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this may not be the most effective way to do it. Here is my answer.

```
SELECT a.*,
    (select Sum(columnA)
     FROM table) as [TotalColumn]
FROM (select Group, Sum(columnA) as SumColumn
      FROM table
      GROUP BY Group) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

well this is odd that you want to display total column sum along with each row. Running total value is what I would expect. but if you want to then it is just a constant number and you can store the Total SUM  Value in variable and then just do the Select Variable in your SLECT FROM TABLE query.

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
        c1  sysname     NOT NULL
        ,c2 int         NOT NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO @table( c1, c2 )
    SELECT 'A',10 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B',20 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C',30

    DECLARE @tSum BIGINT
    SELECT @tSum = SUM(C2) FROM @table

    SELECT c1,c2,@tSum AS Tsum
    FROM @table
```

[image]

Comment: would you explain why? you are saying selecting a constant value as Additional Column in plain select query is slower than performing unnecessary GroupBY+SubQuery ?

Comment: Yes I am, you have all the overhead of creating a table when one is not needed.

Comment: that must be misinterpretation. I am not creating new table. in the example I am declaring table to mimic the OP's original table. Declared Table is the actual Table that user is querying against. why would I create new table to get total SUM of one column. Now you make me thinking is my answer that confusing that some would think I am creating new table to get SUM of one column ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Group,t.SumColumn, 
       (SELECT SUM(a.SumColumn) 
          FROM Table a
         WHERE a.Group=t.Group) TotalColumn
FROM Table t
```

Answer (score 0):

hello this worked for me

```
select a.id,a.val1,b.val2,e.s 
from tbl1 as a 
inner join ( select c1,sum(val1) as s from tbl2 group by c1) as e
    on a.c1=e.c1
```

Comment: This would not run -- you reference a table alias "b" in the select statement that is not in your query.